# Spring Hibernate - saving a one to many association

Tags: spring, hibernate

I would like to save a one to many relationship into the database. In this case one parent and two children.

DAO code

```
   public void createMatch() {

        UserEntity checker = new UserEntity();

        UserEntity  setter = new UserEntity();
        setter.setChecker(checker);
        checker.addSetter(setter);

        if (checker != null)
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(checker); 
        }
```

The model code

```
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

   @ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
   @JoinColumn(name="checker_id")
   private UserEntity checker;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="checker", orphanRemoval=true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<UserEntity> setters = new HashSet<UserEntity>();

    // getters and setters

   public void addSetter(UserEntity setter) {
    if(setters == null) {

        setters = new HashSet<UserEntity>();
    }
    setter.setChecker(this);

    this.setters.add(setter);

}
```

Jsp

Controller for post process

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/student", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView hello(@ModelAttribute("checker") UserEntity checker) { 

        userService.createMatch();

        return new ModelAndView ("redirect:/admin");}
```

The db it is saving to:

```
    CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
    `checker_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
     FOREIGN KEY (`checker_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`));
```

The problem is that one one child is saved for the parent, and when it is saved all of the fields are shown to be null except for the userId. I would like to persist more than one object for a parent and have the values show up in the database. I would like to ask how I go about implementing it?

Answer (score 0):

Your `hello()` method takes a checker as argument, but ignores it completely. It calls `createMatch()`, without any argument, which saves an empty checker containing an empty setter. So the result is quite expected.

For the othe fields to be filled, you have to fill them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I amended the code to take an argument. It is saving not only the parent but the children in the same row with the same id. The is an error.